# Surfboard SB6183 cable modem not working with Belkin 600N wireless router

Tags: wireless-networking, router, modem

I have a new Surfboard SB6183 cable modem which I want to use with a Belkin 600N wireless router.

The SB6183 cable modem works, if I connect it to the internet COAX and to my computer.

The 600N wireless router works if I connect it to a different, older cable modem (Surfboard SB5120) that is connected to the internet COAX.  I can connect via wifi and cable to the router and have internet access.

If I swap out the SB5120 cable modem for the newer SB6813 cable modem, the router light will turn red (no connection) instead of blue (connection) and I will not have any internet access from wifi or wire from router.  I am using the same cables when I switch from one cable modem to the other.

The SB6183 cable modem is a factory replacement for one that went bad.  The router worked with the old SB6183 before it failed.

So...

working: Internet -> SB5120 modem -> 600N router -> computer (wired or wifi)

working: Internet -> SB6183 modem -> computer (wired)

desired but failing: Internet -> SB6183 modem -> 600N router (indicates no connection) Wired and wifi internet access not available.

There are no firmware updates for the Surfboard SB6183.  The Belkin 600N router has the latest updates.

Any ideas on why the Belkin 600N wireless router won't work with the new Surfboard SB6183?

Comment: Is the router getting a WAN IP?

Comment: I found a similar post for a different belkin router and surfboard modem that walked me through how to get it working. One issue I have is that the modem takes longer to initialize and get the IP address than the router does to initialize.  This results in the router not being connected.  If I turn on the router after the modem is initialized, it works.  Didn't have this problem with the older surfboard modem.